# What is this funniest-shaped flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

What is this funniest-shaped flower?

The plant is 3ft high and growing. Unknown origin.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a Prince's Feather, Amaranthus hypochondriacus. It has the small clusters of tiny flowers that Hortus Third calls "chaffy", like the closely related Celosia.

Comment: Yes, Amaranthus!